# getting and settings CPU registers of multiple threads using ptrace

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, ptrace

I am interested in running a multithreaded application in the supervision of another monitoring process. The monitoring process should be able to get and set CPU registers of all the threads in the monitored application. I know how to do this for a single threaded application. But I'm interested in knowing how to extend this for multithreaded applications.

Comment: Seems like I have asked a very difficult question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread id instead of pid in ptrace and it should work fine. However thread management needs to be done by you.

Comment: So u mean I will have to wait for each thread separately using waitpid to get or modify their registers?

Answer (score 0):

Use thread id instead of pid in ptrace, is not a solution. 
Because in Linux-64, pthread_t--unsigned long, pid_t--unsigned int.
I wondered this issue, too.
I have another method to get thread-reg-info, using gdb.
This is my code:

```
void *ThrFunc(void *para)
{
    printf("hello world.\n");
    sleep(-1);      // suspend the thread.
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t ptid;
    int ret = pthread_create(&ptid, NULL, ThrFunc, NULL);
    if(ret != 0)
    {   
        exit(errno);
    }   

    pthread_join(ptid, NULL);// suspend the main thread.

    return 0;
}
```

The following is gdb debug details:

```
(gdb) info thread
  2 Thread 0x7ffff7fe9700 (LWP 4533)  0x00000033d98ab91d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
* 1 Thread 0x7ffff7feb720 (LWP 4530)  0x00000033d9c080ad in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) info reg
rax            0xfffffffffffffe00   -512
...
rip            0x33d9c080ad 0x33d9c080ad <pthread_join+269>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
...
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff7fe9700 (LWP 4533))]#0  0x00000033d98ab91d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) info thread
* 2 Thread 0x7ffff7fe9700 (LWP 4533)  0x00000033d98ab91d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  1 Thread 0x7ffff7feb720 (LWP 4530)  0x00000033d9c080ad in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) info reg
rax            0xfffffffffffffdfc   -516
...
rip            0x33d98ab91d 0x33d98ab91d <nanosleep+45>
eflags         0x293    [ CF AF SF IF ]
...
```

I hope this will help you.
By the way, I also want to know: How to use ptrace() to get a thread registers details？